# How to change UISegmentcontrol font and selected segment colour?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color)
>   [UISegmentcontrol appearances causing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415922/uisegmentcontrol-appearances-causing-issues)

Hi i will like to change the default UISegmentControl font to a custom font and change the selected segment color to another color instead of a darker color.

thanks

from this

[image]

to this

[image]

**EDIT:Solution**
 called

//change font size, remove shadow, selected text & background color are different from normal state

```
-(void)defineSegmentControlStyle
    {
        //normal segment
        NSDictionary *normalAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rok" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                    [UIColor colorWithRed:75.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                    [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                    nil];//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
        [infoSegment setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rok" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                          [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                          [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                          [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                          nil] ;//[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:  [UIColor redColor]forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
        [infoSegment setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5932524/102937

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this:
http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/11/custom-segmented-controls/

Comment: thanks for the reply, i saw that however i need to set a custom font too...

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5059-change-font-size-text-uisegmentedcontrol.html

Comment: Is it possible to change font size of selected segment different from unselected ones in UISegmentedControl?                        I can change the Color of selected segment but not the font size.