# How do I change selected colour and style of UISegmentView? objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to make a uisegmentcontrol where the selected colour is something other than blue. Also I would like to change the style like the image below. Is any of these two things possible and how do you do it?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change UISegmentcontrol font and selected segment colour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426760/how-to-change-uisegmentcontrol-font-and-selected-segment-colour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with custom images using the `UISegmentedControl` instance methods such as `setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:`, `setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:` and `setDividerImage:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:barMetrics`

You could also just use `UIButton`s to mimic the behavior of a `UISegmentedControl`

Comment: Thanks I decided easiest way would be just to use buttons. took me about half an hour.